# Filtering Out DataFrame using filter on GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, pandas-groupby

> Dataset:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/v9gmgxupkypn5dw/train-data.csv

```
conversion_table = {
    1998: 3.7327,
    1999: 3.2372,
    2000: 3.2216,
    2001: 3.1133,
    2002: 2.9603,
    2003: 2.8694,
    2004: 2.7662,
    2005: 2.6652,
    2006: 2.5246,
    2007: 2.3702,
    2008: 2.2461,
    2009: 2.0475,
    2010: 1.7809,
    2011: 1.6270,
    2012: 1.5278,
    2013: 1.3743,
    2014: 1.2594,
    2015: 1.1897,
    2016: 1.1189,
    2017: 1.0945,
    2018: 1.0524,
    2019: 1.0}
```

Using the provided dictionary, adjust New_Price for inflation by doing the following:

```
     a   Make a function called inflation that inputs a dataframe.

     b   Make a new variable conversion. This is a column with the values of conversion_table that matches the column Year as the key.

     c   Remove any non-numerical characters in the column New_Price. Replace the New_Price with that change.

     d   Convert the column type New_Price into float. Replace the New_Price with that change.

     e   Multiply New_Price with conversion. Replace the New_Price with that change.

     f   Return the dataframe.
     
     Then, Print Year, New_Price, and New_Price_Adjusted.
```

> My codes are below:

```
def inflation(df):
  conversion = conversion_table[df["Year"].values[0]]
  df['New_Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['New_Price'], errors='coerce')
  df = df.dropna(subset=['New_Price'])
  df["New_Price"] = df["New_Price"].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')
  df["New_Price"] = df["New_Price"] * df["conversion"]
  return df

df = df.groupby("Year").apply(inflation)
print(df[["Year","New_Price"]])
```

> KeyError: 'conversion'

If I delete this:
*df = df.groupby("Year").apply(inflation)*
it works without error, but I think I need to use this code because I have to class that function. Right? Anyone can please give me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting this error because here in the line `df[df.New_Price.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())].set_index('New_Price')`  the column `New_Price` is of type `float` and `isnumeric()` works on string so if you want to use this code then convert it to string by `astype()` method i.e `df[df.New_Price.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())].set_index('New_Price')`

Comment: then how can I do? it seems I need to delete/Remove any non-numerical characters in the column New_Price. LoL

Comment: you are using `pd.to_numeric()` here `df["New_Price"] = df["New_Price"].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')` this will turns the non numeric value to NaN's then use `dropna()` method to remove that non numeric rows that are converted to NaN's by `to_numeric()` method

Comment: df['New_Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['New_Price'], errors='coerce')
  df = df.dropna(subset=['New_Price']) I tried to use this to instead the original one. but new errors happened. ---->KeyError: 'conversion'

Comment: This was because no column named `conversion` exists in your df....check this line inside your function `df["New_Price"] = df["New_Price"] * df["conversion"]`

Comment: there is a table, updated.conversion_table = {    1998: 3.7327,
    1999: 3.2372,
    2000: 3.2216}

Comment: Make a new variable conversion. This is a column with the values of conversion_table that matches the column Year as the key. --->conversion = conversion_table[df["Year"].values[0]]

Comment: but you are multiplying `df["New_Price"]` that something doesn't exist in your data frame `df["conversion"]`

Comment: dep_plus_arr = df["New_Price"] 
  df["New_Price"] = (dep_plus_arr * conversion).round(1) ---->it works

Comment: another new error, df = df.groupby("Year").apply(inflation) : ValueError: 'Year' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: try `df.groupby("Year",as_index=False).apply(inflation)`

Comment: But the output of Price are full of NaN, How to fix this issue???